# Can’t render animation also if frame range is ok

Tags: rendering, animation

I’m trying to render an animation but Blender exports just the 1st frame. Why?

My frame range is 1/200
And I also choose the output folder and the format I tied with different ones none of them seems working.

Also the compositing nodetree seems ok.

Its my first time using Blender.

Blender File https://drive.google.com/file/d/11G615FLZm5JV06vt-saAD9GfPTFzucJT/view?usp=share_link

Answer (score 0):

In your *Output Properties* under *Frame Range* (which is 0/200 by the way, not 1/200 as stated in the question) you have set the *Step* to 0 (which the slider would not even allow, so you seem to have set it intentionally - why?). That *Step* is how much frames Blender will move forward after rendering a frame. 0 frames forward means it will always stay on the first frame, because *Start* + 0 = *Start*. Set it to the default 1 (or higher if you want to skip frames for a quick overview render).

[image: render steps]